# Replicating struct in python

Tags: python, struct

Is there anyway to support structures in python and does it not support the normal keyword *struct*?

for eg:

```
struct node
{
  unsigned dist[20];
  unsigned from[20];
}rt[10];
```

How can i covert this into a python struct?

Comment: Just as a side note: If you want to make python interact with c data types you should have a look at the ctypes module.

Comment: Calling the `struct` keyword "normal" indicates to me that you are thinking strictly in terms of a line-by-line translation of C into Python. I suggest at the very least you start by reading a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) on Python programming.

Comment: @chepner no i mean emulating c-structures

Comment: So do I, unless you are looking for the [`struct` package](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/struct.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the Python's equivalent to C-structs is [`classes`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dist_ = []
        self.from_ = []

rt = []
```

Comment: `from` is a keyword in Python; that'll give a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Generally to avoid name clashes with built-in you should use *trailing* underscores, since *leading* underscore are conventioanlly used to indicate "private" variables.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Thanks. See my edited post. Is this a PEP8's convention or something?

Comment: Exactly. See [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). In particular "`_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. " and "`single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword"

Comment: Thanks.So do i just use dist and from as lists?

Comment: @Abhishek Herle: Yes. You can use `dist` and `from` as lists in which you put whatever you want :)

Comment: @segfolt What about rt=[] can you elaborate a little on that

Comment: @Abhishek Herle: `rt` is a list in which you can add `Node` objects(structs in C) like that: http://ideone.com/M2xzWj

Comment: @segfolt Thank u so much.One last doubt is there any way to create those nodes dynamically?Hope I haven't been a burden.

Comment: @Abhishek Herle: If I correctly understood your question: yes ou also create `Nodes` that way: http://ideone.com/JOyhj7

Comment: @segfolt I should have figured that one out thank you.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since the ordering of attributes (unless an `OrderedDict` or something is used to `__prepare__` or otherwise build the class) is not necessarily in order of definition, if you wanted to be compatible with an actual C `struct` or rely on data being in some order, then the following is a base you should be able to use (using `ctypes`).

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dist', c_uint * 20),
        ('from', c_uint * 20)
    ]
```

Comment: @AbhishekHerle It might be best if you had a read through http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html - that'll give you a decent overview

Answer (score 1):

Even an empty class would do:

```
In [1]: class Node: pass
In [2]: n = Node()
In [3]: n.foo = [1,2,4]
In [4]: n.bar = "go"
In [8]: print n.__dict__
{'foo': [1, 2, 4], 'bar': 'go'}
In [9]: print n.bar
go
```

Comment: Adding attributes in this way, although possible, is mostly a bag practice. Anyway, in python3.3+ you don't even have to create the empty class. Simple use [`SimpleNamespace`](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#simplenamespace).

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek-Herle

If I would have been in your situation, I might rely on Struct module in python.

Like, in your case C structure is:

```
struct node
{
  unsigned dist[20];
  unsigned from[20];
}rt[10];
```

So here basic idea is to convert C-Structure to python and vice a versa. I can roughly define above c-structure in below python code.

```
s = struct.Sturct('I:20 I:20')
```

Now, if I want to pack any values to this structure I can do, some thing like below.

```
dist = [1, 2, 3....20]
from = [1, 2, 3....20]
s.pack(*dist, *from)
print s #this would be binary representation of your C structure
```

Obviously, you can unpack back it using s.unpack method.